# Printing labels on vector layers by geoserver print module (MapFish)

Tags: pdf, label, geoserver

I use MapFish plugin for geoserver. Vector layers are printed fine but text labels on them do not appear in pdf. Although they are visible on the map before printing.

Help me please =)

Comment: Are you using any client-side style?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use latest mapfish-print. You need to download and compile it as described here https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print

Comment: For a better answer, can you add a reference to where it states that the OP's issue has been fixed? Thanks.